# "goog.proto2.Message.set$Metadata" undefined error

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, libphonenumber

I'm using Google closure [online compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) for libphonenumber. Here is the compiler code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @use_closure_library true
// @code_url http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/phonemetadata.pb.js
// @code_url http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/phonenumber.pb.js
// @code_url http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/metadatalite.js
// @code_url http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.js
// @code_url http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/asyoutypeformatter.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

This compiles successfully, but when i include compiled js file in html then it gives error: *undefined is not a function*, line 196 
 
I suspect it have something to do with *goog.require('goog.proto2.Message');*, but no luck so far. 
Final goal is to make phone number validation, something like this:

```
var phoneUtil = i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
var number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput('1234567899', 'XX');
var isNumberValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number);
```

How to solve *TypeError: goog.proto2.Message.set$Metadata is not a function*?

Comment: Your hunch is correct. Add the `@warning_level VERBOSE` option and you'll get compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set$Metadata` method was removed in this commit: https://github.com/google/closure-library/commit/d49d52de4577aea38dd0d3ec76a931c2f551dbf3

Comment: Thanks! Using latest version of libphonenumber code solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google moved the code to [Github](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) then use the following code in [Google online closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to get the latest:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name libphonenumber.js
// @use_closure_library true
// @code_url https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/raw/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/phonemetadata.pb.js
// @code_url https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/raw/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/phonenumber.pb.js
// @code_url https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/raw/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/metadata.js
// @code_url https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/raw/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.js
// @code_url https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/raw/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/asyoutypeformatter.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```